# How to make custom scanner in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to make a custom scanner of upto 40 symbols and this code works as i want it to in a single symbol but i am unable to create a scanner with this code as the "or" function has some issues, i think.

```
//@version=5
indicator("EMA RSI")

emas  = input(close, "EMA Source")
ema1l = input(13, "EMA 1 Length") 
ema2l = input(21, "EMA 2 Length")
ema3l = input(34, "EMA 3 Length")
ema1 = ta.ema(emas, ema1l)
ema2 = ta.ema(emas, ema2l)
ema3 = ta.ema(emas, ema3l)

plot(ema1, color = color.green, linewidth = 2)
plot(ema2, color = color.red, linewidth = 2)
plot(ema3, color = color.black, linewidth = 2)


rsil = input.int(14, "RSI Length")
rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsil)
rsiub = input(60.0, "RSI Upper Band")
rsilb = input(40.0, "RSI Lower Band")
rsimb = input(50.0, "RSI Middle Band") 

l = ema1 > ema2 or ta.crossover(ema1, ema2)
l1 = ema2 > ema3 or ta.crossover(ema2, ema3)
l2 = rsi > rsiub or ta.crossover(rsi, rsiub)

s = ema1 < ema2 or ta.crossunder(ema1, ema2)
s1 = ema2 < ema3 or ta.crossunder(ema2, ema3)
s2 = rsi < rsilb or ta.crossunder(rsi, rsilb)

Long = l and l1 and l2
Short = s and s1 and s2

plotshape(Long[1], style = shape.diamond, location = location.abovebar, color = color.green, size = size.small, text = "Long")
plotshape(Short[1], style = shape.diamond, location = location.belowbar, color = color.red, size = size.small, text = "Short")


if (Long[1])
    alert("Long")   

if(Short[1])
    alert("Short")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the security function
I made an example here: https://www.tradingview.com/script/om1WoPb0-Ultimate-Screener-Template/

Enjoy :)